# Filter records where row_number() is 1

Tags: sql

```
select 
    account_num,load_date, xyz, abc, pqr
    row_number() over(partition by account_num order by load_date desc) as rn
from 
    balance,
where 
    tran_code = 123
```

I am getting o/p of this code. Now I want to extract those rows where rn = 1. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a common table expression:

```
with b as ( 
   select account_num, load_date, xyz, abc, pqr
      row_number() over(partition by load_date order by load_date desc) as rn
    from balance
    where tran_code = 123
)
select account_num, load_date, xyz, abc, pqr
from b
where rn=1;
```

Comment: It makes no sense to both partition and order by the same column `load_date`.  The OP should clarify the ranking logic, but in any case what your answer says likely is not what is wanted here.

Comment: Updated the same, but I think Stu got my problem and his solution was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Note that on some databases (e.g. Teradata, BigQuery), we can avoid a formal subquery and instead use the `QUALIFY` clause:

```sql
SELECT account_num, load_date, xyz, abc, pqr
FROM balance
WHERE tran_code = 123
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION load_date ORDER BY <col>) = 1;
```

On SQL Server, we can avoid a subquery using a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES account_num, load_date, xyz, abc, pqr
FROM balance
WHERE tran_code = 123
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION load_date ORDER BY <col>);
```

Your calls to `ROW_NUMBER` should probably have an `ORDER BY` clause to make sense.

Comment: While it does avoid a subquery, should it? Order by row_number(), at least in SQL Server, requires an additional sort and is a more costly alternative.